# Cognos 8.4.1 St9bad_alloc message : how to solve?

Tags: cognos

For eval purpose; I installed Cognos 8.4.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.
The DB for the content store is Oracle 11g with AL32 UTF8 character set.
Crypto keys are stored locally. Env is set as recommended.

When trying to start the service, even before creating the content store, I get this message :

CM-CFG-5076 A Content Manager configuration error occurred during the initialization of Cognos Access Manager.  CAM-AAA-0071 An internal error occurred.  St9bad_alloc

Any idea of the cause ?

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: My recommendation: Try it on CentOS instead.  Ubuntu isn't at all a supported Linux distribution for Cognos, but RedHat is.  You're likely running into some library mismatch/issue that was never remotely tested against.

Comment: Well, changing OS is not in my projects :-) ... but I have Cognos running on an old Windows XP virtual machine which may do the job if no other suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a supported distribution would definitely be a good idea.  That said, if you stop cognos, rename the cogserver.log file (by default this is in /logs under your installation directory), start cognos up again and post the generated log file we might get more detail about what's stopping it.

Comment: Indeed, moving to a supported distro solved the dependencies issues. Thanks Alexis.